# How to resize all the layers?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, cs6, scale

I'm working with a graphic designer who doesn't know how to design for the web, I can't blame her, she's not a web designer.

She keeps sending me pictures and PSDs that seem too big, I do my estimations and create them using CSS, she sees them and says it's too big. In the screenshot I can see that an image is 70% or 80% the width of the screen, so I do it as I see it, but her measurements are different.

The main problem is that she doesn't know how to specify how big her images should be in terms of percentages and the average width of an image is 1100px. She doesn't know that the average screen size is 1024.

I need a way to scale everything down to 1024px so that I can test her precise design on real screens and then convert them back to percentages. If that task can be automated then there's no need to ask her, she's comfortable working with a big scale and I respect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the images are bigger than 1024 px, go to the **Actions Panel** and create a new action using:

**Menu File** > **Automate** > **Fit Image**

[image: FIT IMAGE]

And apply this action to each image or go to:

**Menu File** > **Automate** > **Batch** to apply this action to all the images in a folder

Comment: what if some images are icons? basically she sends a template, the base layer is bigger than 1024, hence her entire website is bigger but some images like social media aren't bigger

Comment: Could you put an image sample on the question please? There are many possibilities but all of them depends on the image type: transparent background, white background, smart objects, etc. Always you can make an action, but just if all the images have a common type.

Comment: I think that did the trick however the height is tricky, is there a way to resize the height in a way proportional to the width? because the width is fixed 1024 but the height isn't

Comment: You can put the height at 300000 because **Don't Enlarge** is checked. the only reference measure will be the width, the height will change proportionally.